# How to define the Holder space on unit sphere?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We know the definition of Holder space $C^{0,\gamma}$ on the domain $U$ (an open and connect domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$):
$$C^{0,\gamma}=\left\{\,u\,\Big|\,\sup\limits_{x,y\in U,x\neq y}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}<+\infty\,\right\}.$$
But how can we define the Holder space on unit sphere
$$B_1=\left\{\,x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,|\,|x|=1\,\right\}.$$

I would appriciate it if someone could give me a definition or a reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define $C^{0,\gamma}(X)$ on any metric space $(X,d)$ with basically the same formula, i.e.,
$$
C^{0,\gamma}(X)=\left\{f\in\mathbb{R}^X:
\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert}{d(x,y)^\gamma}<\infty\right\}.
$$
You usually want to impose $\sup\lvert f\rvert<\infty$ too if $X$ is not compact, so you have norm
$$
\lVert f\rVert_{C^{0,\gamma}}=\sup\lvert f\rvert+
\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert}{d(x,y)^\gamma}
$$
and embedding $C^{0,\beta}(X)\subseteq C^{0,\gamma}(X)\subseteq C(X)$ for $\beta>\gamma>0$.

Sometimes you will see Hölder spaces defined by changing the metric $d$ to $\tilde{d}=\max(d,d^\gamma)$ ($0<\gamma<1$) and $C^{0,\gamma}(X,d):=\operatorname{Lip}(X,\tilde{d})$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For example, let $n>3$ and $\phi(x)=\ln|x-\xi|$ with $\xi\in \text{int}\,B_1$, then 
$$\|\phi\|_{C^{2,\gamma}\;(\partial B_1)}=\sum_{i=0}^2\sup|D^i\phi|+\sup_{x,y\in\partial B_1, x\neq y}\frac{|D^2\phi(x)-D^2\phi(y)|}{d^\gamma(x,y)}.$$
But what's the meaning of $D^i\phi$ on $\partial B_1$?

Comment: You can either "cheat" and use the fact that you live in $\mathbb{R}^n$, define $\phi$ using the same formula on $\mathbb{R}^n-\{\xi\}$ and compute the derivatives, then restrict to the unit sphere.  Or you can use the unit sphere is a smooth (Riemannian) manifold and define the derivative as in basic differential geometry.

Comment: It's very kind of you to give me such a reply patiently. I have to admit that I didn't study differential geometry.

Comment: In which case, I'll very quickly summarise: extend $\phi$ to a sufficiently smooth $\tilde\phi\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$, some open $U\supset\partial B_1$.  At any $x\in\partial B_1$, you consider the usual $D^i\tilde\phi(x)$ as a multilinear map $\underbrace{\mathbb{R}^n\times\dots\times\mathbb{R}^n}_i\to\mathbb{R}$, except now you need to restrict that to only the tangential part of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., $x^\perp$ in place of each $\mathbb{R}^n$ factor, and call it $D^i\phi(x)$.  It can be shown that this doesn't depend on the extension $\tilde\phi$, so we can use $\tilde\phi(x)=\ln |x-\xi|$.